# How to change the value for an entry in a properties file using shell script

Tags: shell

I've to change the value for an entry in a properties file.The properties file will have an entry in 7th line as

```
baseDir={baseDIR}
```

the cat and grep for the above line is easy, but i'm not sure how i've to put my custom value after "=" and insert it into the file.

i want to change it to

```
baseDir=/home/db/<new folder>/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [`replace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/replace) utility:

```
burhan@sandbox:~$ cat test.cat
foo=bar
zoo=blah
abc
def
1234
baseDir={baseDir}
something
something-else
burhan@sandbox:~$ replace {baseDir} /home/burhan -- test.cat
test.cat converted
burhan@sandbox:~$ cat test.cat
foo=bar
zoo=blah
abc
def
1234
baseDir=/home/burhan
something
something-else
```

If this is not installed (it comes with MySQL), you can use `perl`:

```
burhan@sandbox:~$ perl -pi -w -e 's/\/home\/burhan/{baseDir}/g;' < test.cat
foo=bar
zoo=blah
abc
def
1234
baseDir={baseDir}
something
something-else
```

Or `sed` (but you have to make sure you escape the `\` character if you are going to write a path):

```
burhan@sandbox:~$ cat test.cat
foo=bar
zoo=blah
abc
def
1234
baseDir={baseDir}
something
something-else

burhan@sandbox:~$ sed -i 's/{baseDir}/\/home\/burhan\//' test.cat
burhan@sandbox:~$ cat test.cat
foo=bar
zoo=blah
abc
def
1234
baseDir=/home/burhan/
something
something-else
```